# Keyboard shortcuts that I change from system preference don't work everywhere, even though the initial shortcut used to work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I changed a lot of keyboard shortcuts to make the experience similar to windows by going to system preference -> keyboard -> shortcuts. For example I changed command+c/v/x/a/z to control+c/v/x/a/z. They all seemed to work at first, but after using my mac for a while with different applications, they seem to not always work. I did put all the shortcuts under the "All applications" tab so they should work everywhere.

For example, while writing this question, I cannot use any of those shortcuts in this editor (pressing them doesn't do anything), except for ctrl+z. I also noticed that ctrl+a doesn't work in the google.ca search bar. I'm currently using google chrome, but tried them in safari and the same issues arises. There were also some application were control+c wouldn't work. So this seem to be specific to some webpage and applications.

Keep in mind that command+c/v/x/a/z all work everywhere (i.e. everything work before trying my new ctrl shortcuts).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Exchange uses ctrl + [key] for several of its own built-in text operations. You're fighting not one paradigm but two. Honestly, & speaking as a Mac user for 30 years & Windows for 20, it's just easier to learn the differences than try to force them into an impossible homogeneity.

Comment: Isn't it better if you "swap" Command with CTRL? In keyboard preferences there is a possibility to remap "Modifier Keys" (I do that with CMD<->ALT). CTRL shortcuts you use may interfere with "Emacs text" keymapping.

Comment: @Tetsujin But on windows there is no such problem, so I don't think it because of built-in text operations, unless the built in text operations of Stack Exchange change when you change operating system.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a Command key. There is no problem because Windows has to give way to Stack Exchange [or any similar usage] in such circumstances. The Mac doesn't need to because its keys don't conflict with SE's markdown implementation… until you try to fight it by making your own custom keyset.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I didn't know I could do that. I just google how to swap copy and paste shortcut and the first answer was to into keyboard -> shortcuts. This would really help a lot (I already wasted time on changing all the shortcuts that finder and chrome use too, so this would have saved me a lot of time). Also why would the shortcuts interfere with Emacs? I use Vim so I don't mind, but windows has all those shortcuts already, so would Emacs behave on windows?

Comment: @MoonlessNightss I call them "Emacs" shortcuts, because thay are similar. Basically text inputs (that are made from AppKit framewrok) have those shortcuts builtin (CTRL+A -> move to the beginning of the line, CTRL+E go to the end of the line etc.) It has nothing to do with Emacs

Comment: @Tetsujin I see. This was helpful. I'll try MateuszSzlosek suggestion to see if it helps in any way, and if not I guess I'll have to learn the mac keybindings :/

Comment: Welcome. The issue with swapping how the keys register to the OS is that you'll still have to remember to do the opposite in various terminals, as Mateusz says, because they already use similar Ctrl/[key] structures to SE

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I see, thank you. Now I understand why my cursor was going at the beginning of the line when I pressed <C-a>, on the Stack Exchange editor. I thought nothing was happening, and it was a bug or something

Comment: @Tetsujin yea the drawback is that you have to remember that your Command is swapped with different key. I regret a bit that I did it 12 years ago, but now it's natural to me. I use a lot of diacritics and it's easier to have ALT next to Space bar :)

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek - for sure. As I used Mac long before Windows, I have to remember it the other way round… but to add to that I have one Mac with a "PC" keyboard & also very often remote into Windows from my regular Mac & keyboard. It's a whole lot to remember, but eventually it becomes habit.